# How to achieve maximum sampling rate in STM32F3, theoretically?

Tags: embedded, stm32, adc

I'm currently using STM32F303VET6 in a project which requires sampling rate as high as possible. I've decided to connect the analog signal to PC0, i.e., ADC12_IN6, which is a common slow channel connected internally to ADC1&2, according to the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0316-stm32f303xbcde-stm32f303x68-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-armbased-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), and then interleavingly sample the channel.

The [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303ve.pdf) specifies that the sampling frequency for slow channels can be 4.8 MSPS, on page 137. This is probably the maximum sampling rate.

However, the datasheet also says on page 135 that for slow channels, the minimum sampling cycle for slow channels is 4.5 cycles, as the R_AIN values for 1.5- and 2.5-cycle are specified NA. Then the minimum conversion time will be 4.5 + 0.5 + 12 cycles, accordingly 4.2 MSPS, slower then the specified 4.8 MSPS.

Of course, I can lower the sampling time, but then the ADC accuracy will not be guaranteed. My questions are:

1. Are there any official documents indicating that 4.8 MSPS on slow channels is available theoretically? (For example, what is the maximum R_AIN in this case?)
2. If so, are there any examples on the Internet?

(Related but not similar: [STM32F3 Dual ADC with interleaved mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024674/stm32f3-dual-adc-with-interleaved-mode))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is available at any resolution lower than 12 bits (ie 10, 8, 6) and it is documented on the same page :)

I Have tested it with 1.5clocks (5.1MSPS) and it was working well if the input signal was coming from the event OP-AMP (very low output impedance and huge slew rate) - bet there is no guarantee from the STM that it will work.

I have corrected it in the second review of the board (I have chosen wrong pins by mistake)